# Detecting EOF in a MySQL Query Result

Tags: php, mysql

I've a MySQL database and one of the columns is 'Address' which sometimes contains more then 1 row. For instance I have the following address:

`Street X, Block Y,
Apartment Z, Door W`

When I will get data from MySQL and `echo` it I'd end up with:

`Street X, Block Y, Apartment Z, Door W`

How do I detect the end of row in MySQL so I can add a `. <br>` ?

Comment: you can use `nl2br($data)` in PHP and new lines will be converted to `<br>` here `$data` is the value from table.

Comment: That did the trick! If you want, add that as an answer so I can mark it as the answer for other readers. I've noticed there's no other such thing in the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function, which has following the description:

> Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

So finally the code to do your task will be as simple as

`$address = nl2br($address);`

Answer (score 1):

I think `nl2br($data)` is a good but dirty solution since it adds only `<br>`

I will suggest to use this expression `'/[\r\n]+/'` to identify the special endline characters

For example

```
$text = trim($text);
'<youtag>' . preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '</youtag><youtag>', $text) . '</youtag>';
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you've got a newline character in the appropriate place in the data stored in MySQL, but the newline isn't being displayed correctly when you query the table. One option is to use a MySQL query that replaces the newline character with the line break string:

```
SELECT REPLACE(`Address`, '\n', '<br>') FROM mydatabase.mytable;
```